# sorry, i can not keep dictionary "ordered"

Tags: python, dictionary

the python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) has the tutorial (attached below), but i keep getting the error [message](http://screencloud.net/v/wlWT) "NameError: name 'OrderedDict' is not defined"

not sure what is wrong, i am pretty sure my python is 2.7+ (which should support the sorted dictionary)

```
>>> # regular unsorted dictionary
>>> d = {'banana': 3, 'apple':4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}

>>> # dictionary sorted by key
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
OrderedDict([('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)])

>>> # dictionary sorted by value
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
OrderedDict([('pear', 1), ('orange', 2), ('banana', 3), ('apple', 4)])

>>> # dictionary sorted by length of the key string
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: len(t[0])))
OrderedDict([('pear', 1), ('apple', 4), ('orange', 2), ('banana', 3)])
```

Comment: Did you import it? `from collections import OrderedDict`

Comment: amazing, it works, why they do not include that piece of code in the tutorial, hard for the begineer

Comment: @user381509 ... because you are looking at the collections module documentation ... by the time you are doing that you should know about imports ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html):

> This module implements specialized container datatypes providing **alternatives to Python’s general purpose built-in containers**, dict, list, set, and tuple.

which means `collections.OrderedDict` is not a built-in container, and you should import it:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
```

Comment: thanks for the answers, since they are now ordered, is there any syntax to locate any values or keys at particular location? thanks

Comment: i found a "hard" way to do it by firstly convert the sorted dictionary to dic.values, than locate over the list. not sure any simplier way?

Comment: Can you describe **exactly** what you are doing? python mappings (`dict`) can be reversed easily most of the time. If it's not in the scope of this question try a bit and open a new question when you've given up.